# Trying (and failing) to run Hello World 32-bit C++ program on 64-bit Ubuntu on Windows 10

Tags: c++, ubuntu, 32bit-64bit, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I configured my new Ubuntu on Windows 10 from scratch in the following way:

```
# apt-get update
# apt-get install build-essential
# # Am able to compile now using "g++ -Wall -o Hello-World Hello-World.cpp", the binary is working.

# # To check versions, and that both packages were indeed installed
# gcc -v
    # make -v

# apt-get install g++-multilib
# # This also installs gcc-multilib as a dependency
# # Now able to compile using "g++ -m32 -Wall -o Hello-World Hello-World.cpp
# # However the binary Hello-World can't be run. Error message "bash: ./Hello-World: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

# apt-get install lib32gcc1 lib32stdc++6
# # Those two packages are at this time already both installed and well

# dpkg --add-architecture i386
# apt-get update
# apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
# # Still getting the same error when wanting to ./Hello-World
```

I guess I'm still missing an `xyz:i386 library`, I just couldn't figure it out by myself which one's still missing. Also I'm not sure if this is an "Ubuntu on Windows"-specific thing, or if this would also have occured when procceeding the same way on a normal Ubuntu 64-bit OS. Do you have any suggestions?

And for completion, this is the content of the `Hello-World.cpp` file:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char **argv)

{

    cout << "Hellobaby" << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is "ubuntu on Windows 10?"

Comment: @SamVarshavchik it's the new linux subsystem in windows 10, which is basically bash on windows 10 (only in insider builds currently)

Comment: Windows 10 is getting a Bash environment. Everybody part of the Fast Ring-Insider Program can already test it right now. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about

Comment: That looks to me like the 64-bit Windows environment does not support loading 32-bit executables. Either that, or gcc is not emitting the right binary-fu. No amount of installing additional libraries will help. This error appears to be a loading error, and not an error related to resolving undefined library references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that Sam Varshavchik was right, and Ubuntu on Windows doesn't currently support 32-bit architectured programs. I installed a virtual Ubuntu 64-bit on VirtualBox, and there - using the exact same commands as described in my initial post - the program compiles and runs.

Thanks everybody for your comments

Answer (score 1):

I think you didn't installed all the g++ related dependencies. Execute the below mentioned commands for installing the dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: No that's not it. You have to use the -m32 flag in order to compile it as a 32-bit binary. I used "g++ -m32 -Wall -o Hello-World Hello-World.cpp".

Comment: @Mandelbrot: Why do you think you have to compile to 32-bit? WSL can only execute ELF-64 binaries.

Answer (score 1):

QEMU and binfmt support light the way :)

https://github.com/microsoft/wsl/issues/2468#issuecomment-374904520

After reading that the WSLInterop between WSL and Windows processes used binfmt, I was tinkering with QEMU to try some ARM development, and incidentally discovered how to get 32-bit support working.

Requires "Fall Creators Update", 1709, build 16299 or newer

Install qemu and binfmt config:

```
sudo apt install qemu-user-static
sudo update-binfmts --install i386 /usr/bin/qemu-i386-static --magic '\x7fELF\x01\x01\x01\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x03\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00' --mask '\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xfc\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xf8\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff'
```

You'll need to reactivate binfmt support every time you start WSL:

```
sudo service binfmt-support start
```

Enable i386 architecture packages:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
sudo apt install g++:i386
```

Try it out:

```
$ file /usr/bin/g++-5
/usr/bin/g++-5: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=9835ed3e5b1c8707591630e314ba4030a571deec, stripped

$ /usr/bin/g++-5 --version
g++-5 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ g++ -m32 -Wall helloworld.cpp -o helloworld

$ ./helloworld
Hello, world!

$ file helloworld
helloworld: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=65905fae78b837162a29d618b4ce63d300c62cb6, not stripped
```

And to prove it really was working, disable i386 support and try again:

```
$ sudo service binfmt-support stop
 * Disabling additional executable binary formats binfmt-support [ OK ]

$ ./helloworld
-bash: ./helloworld: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```