# i386 32 bit bainary support seems broken - how do I get 32 bit bainaries to execute

Tags: ubuntu, 32bit-64bit

This was working on Ubuntu until recently.

I have had a dual 32/64 bit development environment for several year and recently my 32 bit apps have stopped running.

This seems to fail sometimes because the binfmt-support service fails to start. (However even on new clean install of Ubuntu where the service does not fail 32 bit binaries refuse to run.)

Here is the error:

```
The job identifier is 202.

Feb 13 14:59:06 WZ-M18xR2 update-binfmts[864]: update-binfmts: warning: unable to close /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register: Invalid argument
Feb 13 14:59:06 WZ-M18xR2 update-binfmts[864]: update-binfmts: exiting due to previous errors
Feb 13 14:59:06 WZ-M18xR2 systemd[1]: binfmt-support.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit binfmt-support.service has exited.
░░ 
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 2.
Feb 13 14:59:06 WZ-M18xR2 systemd[1]: binfmt-support.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ The unit binfmt-support.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 13 14:59:06 WZ-M18xR2 systemd[1]: Failed to start Enable support for additional executable binary formats.
```

Finding another old reference that this might be caused by a conflict with systemd-binfmt I stopped systemd-binfmt and tried to restart binfmt-support but still the same error.

However even on a clean built system without this error the 32 bit binaries refuse to run with this error:

```
bash: ./my32app: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

If I try this:

```
/lib32/ld-linux.so.2 ./my32app
./my32app: error while loading shared libraries: ./dcc: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

or this:

```
usr/bin/qemu-i386-static ./dcc
qemu-i386-static: ./my32app: Invalid ELF image for this architecture
```

readelf show the only dependency is:

```
readelf -d ./my32app | grep NEEDED
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```

And libc.so.6 can definitely be found in /lib32

And here is a list of all the installed i386 packages:

```
dpkg -l | awk '/^ii/ && $4 == "i386" { print }'
ii  gcc-12-base:i386                                            12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04                                      i386         GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  libblkid1:i386                                              2.37.2-4ubuntu3                                            i386         block device ID library
ii  libbz2-1.0:i386                                             1.0.8-5build1                                              i386         high-quality block-sorting file compressor library - runtime
ii  libc6:i386                                                  2.35-0ubuntu3.6                                            i386         GNU C Library: Shared libraries
ii  libcap2:i386                                                1:2.44-1ubuntu0.22.04.1                                    i386         POSIX 1003.1e capabilities (library)
ii  libcom-err2:i386                                            1.46.5-2ubuntu1.1                                          i386         common error description library
ii  libcrypt1:i386                                              1:4.4.27-1                                                 i386         libcrypt shared library
ii  libdb5.3:i386                                               5.3.28+dfsg1-0.8ubuntu3                                    i386         Berkeley v5.3 Database Libraries [runtime]
ii  libdbus-1-3:i386                                            1.12.20-2ubuntu4.1                                         i386         simple interprocess messaging system (library)
ii  libgamemode0:i386                                           1.6.1-1build2                                              i386         Optimise Linux system performance on demand (host library)
ii  libgamemodeauto0:i386                                       1.6.1-1build2                                              i386         Optimise Linux system performance on demand (client library)
ii  libgcc-s1:i386                                              12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04                                      i386         GCC support library
ii  libgcrypt20:i386                                            1.9.4-3ubuntu3                                             i386         LGPL Crypto library - runtime library
ii  libgmp10:i386                                               2:6.2.1+dfsg-3ubuntu1                                      i386         Multiprecision arithmetic library
ii  libgpg-error0:i386                                          1.43-3                                                     i386         GnuPG development runtime library
ii  libgpm2:i386                                                1.20.7-10build1                                            i386         General Purpose Mouse - shared library
ii  libgssapi-krb5-2:i386                                       1.19.2-2ubuntu0.3                                          i386         MIT Kerberos runtime libraries - krb5 GSS-API Mechanism
ii  libidn2-0:i386                                              2.3.2-2build1                                              i386         Internationalized domain names (IDNA2008/TR46) library
ii  libk5crypto3:i386                                           1.19.2-2ubuntu0.3                                          i386         MIT Kerberos runtime libraries - Crypto Library
ii  libkeyutils1:i386                                           1.6.1-2ubuntu3                                             i386         Linux Key Management Utilities (library)
ii  libkrb5-3:i386                                              1.19.2-2ubuntu0.3                                          i386         MIT Kerberos runtime libraries
ii  libkrb5support0:i386                                        1.19.2-2ubuntu0.3                                          i386         MIT Kerberos runtime libraries - Support library
ii  liblz4-1:i386                                               1.9.3-2build2                                              i386         Fast LZ compression algorithm library - runtime
ii  liblzma5:i386                                               5.2.5-2ubuntu1                                             i386         XZ-format compression library
ii  libmount1:i386                                              2.37.2-4ubuntu3                                            i386         device mounting library
ii  libncurses5:i386                                            6.3-2ubuntu0.1                                             i386         shared libraries for terminal handling (legacy version)
ii  libncurses6:i386                                            6.3-2ubuntu0.1                                             i386         shared libraries for terminal handling
ii  libncursesw6:i386                                           6.3-2ubuntu0.1                                             i386         shared libraries for terminal handling (wide character support)
ii  libnsl2:i386                                                1.3.0-2build2                                              i386         Public client interface for NIS(YP) and NIS+
ii  libnss-nis:i386                                             3.1-0ubuntu6                                               i386         NSS module for using NIS as a naming service
ii  libnss-nisplus:i386                                         1.3-0ubuntu6                                               i386         NSS module for using NIS+ as a naming service
ii  libpcre2-8-0:i386                                           10.39-3ubuntu0.1                                           i386         New Perl Compatible Regular Expression Library- 8 bit runtime files
ii  libpcre3:i386                                               2:8.39-13ubuntu0.22.04.1                                   i386         Old Perl 5 Compatible Regular Expression Library - runtime files
ii  libselinux1:i386                                            3.3-1build2                                                i386         SELinux runtime shared libraries
ii  libssl3:i386                                                3.0.2-0ubuntu1.14                                          i386         Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries
ii  libstdc++6:i386                                             12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04                                      i386         GNU Standard C++ Library v3
ii  libsystemd0:i386                                            249.11-0ubuntu3.11                                         i386         systemd utility library
ii  libtinfo5:i386                                              6.3-2ubuntu0.1                                             i386         shared low-level terminfo library (legacy version)
ii  libtinfo6:i386                                              6.3-2ubuntu0.1                                             i386         shared low-level terminfo library for terminal handling
ii  libtirpc3:i386                                              1.3.2-2ubuntu0.1                                           i386         transport-independent RPC library
ii  libudev1:i386                                               249.11-0ubuntu3.11                                         i386         libudev shared library
ii  libunistring2:i386                                          1.0-1                                                      i386         Unicode string library for C
ii  libuuid1:i386                                               2.37.2-4ubuntu3                                            i386         Universally Unique ID library
ii  libzstd1:i386                                               1.4.8+dfsg-3build1                                         i386         fast lossless compression algorithm
ii  zlib1g:i386
```

Looking in /usr/share/binfmt I do not see an format for ELF 32 bit support:

```
ls /usr/share/binfmts/
cli                     qemu-arm         qemu-mips64el   qemu-s390x
jar                     qemu-armeb       qemu-mipsel     qemu-sh4
llvm-11-runtime.binfmt  qemu-cris        qemu-mipsn32    qemu-sh4eb
llvm-12-runtime.binfmt  qemu-hexagon     qemu-mipsn32el  qemu-sparc
llvm-14-runtime.binfmt  qemu-hppa        qemu-ppc        qemu-sparc32plus
python2.7               qemu-m68k        qemu-ppc64      qemu-sparc64
python3.10              qemu-microblaze  qemu-ppc64le    qemu-xtensa
qemu-aarch64            qemu-mips        qemu-riscv32    qemu-xtensaeb
qemu-alpha              qemu-mips64      qemu-riscv64
```

So I tried adding support from this post ([Trying (and failing) to run Hello World 32-bit C++ program on 64-bit Ubuntu on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36665669/trying-and-failing-to-run-hello-world-32-bit-c-program-on-64-bit-ubuntu-on-w))

```
sudo apt install qemu-user-static
sudo update-binfmts --install i386 /usr/bin/qemu-i386-static --magic '\x7fELF\x01\x01\x01\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x03\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00' --mask '\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xfc\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xf8\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff'
sudo service binfmt-support start
```

But that didn't work either.  Looking at the hexdump of one of the 32 binaries didn't convince me that the magic value was correct!

```
hexdump ./dcc | head
0000000 457f 464c 0101 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000010 0003 003e 0001 0000 1300 0000 0034 0000
0000020 7320 0000 0000 0000 0034 0020 000c 0028
0000030 0025 0024 0006 0000 0034 0000 0034 0000
0000040 0034 0000 0180 0000 0180 0000 0004 0000
0000050 0004 0000 0003 0000 01b4 0000 01b4 0000
0000060 01b4 0000 001a 0000 001a 0000 0004 0000
0000070 0001 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000080 0000 0000 0908 0000 0908 0000 0004 0000
0000090 1000 0000 0001 0000 1000 0000 1000 0000
```

So I am unable to determine how to get 32 bit binaries (that previously worked) to run under Ubuntu.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: I installed a fresh Armbian AMD64 and configure i386 support and my 32 bit  executables are working.  Now to troubleshoot and get the Ubuntu system working.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs because x32 architecture support has been removed from the Ubuntu kernel after 5.16.  From 5.17 onwards while x32 binaries are still supported in the tool chain they are no longer support in the kernel.

Solutions :

Staying on Ubuntu (Mate):

```
If no source code rollback kernel to 5.15.
If source code recompile for i386 (not as optimal but works)
```

Otherwise:

```
Migrate to another debian platform that provides the kernel support for x32
```

I managed to test this on Armbian for X86_64 kernel 6.2 and x32 is still supported.